# How do I use AFP with Back To My Mac?

Tags: macos, afp, back-to-my-mac

When my Macbook and home Mac were running Mountain Lion, I used Back To My Mac to get to my home system and it showed me all of my drives if I logged in with my normal account credentials.  Since I've upgraded to Mavericks, it appears to be defaulting to Samba instead of AFP because I only see the single read-only SMB share I have set up, and I can't log in with my normal account user/pass.  When I'm at home, if I manually go to afp://ip.address/ it works fine.  Obviously that is not an option with Back To My Mac.  Does anybody know how I can get the afp-over-wan behavior back?  It was really handy!

Answer (score 2):

You can find your Back To My Mac hostname by doing this:

```
% dns-sd -E
Looking for recommended registration domains:
DATE: ---Fri 15 Nov 2013---
12:00:39.211  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     Recommended Registration domain
12:00:39.212  Added     (More)               local
12:00:39.212  Added                          icloud.com
                                             - > btmm
                                             - - > members
                                             - - - > 1234567
```

Using that you can derive the hostname as `computer_name.1234567.members.btmm.icloud.com`. Now use Finder's "Connect To Server..." command and enter `afp://computer_name.1234567..members.btmm.icloud.com` in the dialog box. It works! If your computer name has a space in it, replace it with a hyphen. The hostname should be all lower-case, so if your computer name is "My Mac" use `my-mac.1234567.members.btmm.icloud.com`.

(If your mac is running ssh, you can ssh to it as well, which opens a whole world of secure-tunnelling possibility!)